# Error : The configuration section cannot contain a CDATA or text element

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yjCM.png)

I am getting this error while launching the application locally. Could anybody help on this. Thanks in advance !!

Please do not mark this as duplicate as I am not able to find solution from previous question.

Comment: please help me on this issue for error image click on the blue link above

Comment: I got the mistake. There were extra spaces in my config file.